# ignoreSafeArea(.all,edge:.all) is not working in IOS 16+

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios16, xcode14

I tried so many ways but it's not working. Please, anyone facing the same issue after updating ios 16, or xcode version, or iPhone 14 Simulator

Please, if you are facing the same problem, let me know. 
My old project is working fine, but the new one that I created on it is not working.

any solution on it

```
ZStack {
    Color("BlueColor")
      .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edge:.all)
}
```

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/iMnoorfahad/ios-onBoarding-animation/tree/main/Stater/Screens) Please check if you want to check all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the code provided looks and behaves the same on iOS 15 and iOS 16.

I assume you want `Color("BlueColor")` to fill the entire background? That works perfectly fine, but for some reason your `ContentView` you wrap your views in a `VStack` and apply a `.padding`

Simply remove the `VStack`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("onBoarding") var isOnBoarding = true
    
    var body: some View {
        if isOnBoarding {
            OnboardingView()
        } else {
            Text("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

or if for some reason you need said `VStack` at least remove the padding

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("onBoarding") var isOnBoarding = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isOnBoarding {
                OnboardingView()
            } else {
                Text("Home")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine i though it's some error in ignoresafeare but it's in main thanks